# How to prevent user mouse-click interactivity with Flex Spark slider?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using Flex Spark Slider as a time-line for a Flex video player custom component I have created.

I want to prevent the user from clicking on the slider and changing its value, but at the same time I should be able to change the value of the slider programmatically.

Setting the "enabled" property for the slider to "false" doesn't help as then I am not able to change the slider value programmatically.

Any clue, how to achieve this behavior?

Comment: have you tried setting mouseChildren=false ?

Comment: yup, Dan is right :)
mouseChildren = false; mouseEnabled = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have a single element that needs to have the mouse disabled, use the [mouseEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) property.  If however you have child elements on a particular object that you want to cascade the disabling of the mouse events to, make sure to set the [mouseChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren) property as well.  This second one has caught me before when I was still getting a response to mouse events even though I though I had disabled them.  For what you need, sounds like setting mouseEnabled should be enough.